# why all variable names and values are not displayed When using method="post" in HTML forms

Tags: php, http-post

i m getting confuse taking to that question why all variable names and values not show in url when we use method "post" in HTML forms.

i hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because POST requests include variables to message body and not URL. See this: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html (Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference? )

Answer (score 0):

Only GET methods show the variable names and values in the URL, not POST methods

Answer (score 0):

When you are using POST method than all the data like your variable name,variable value, cookie is send to server in Request body,

so you cant see that parameter while using POST.

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST methods are two different way to exchange data between server and client.

GET - retrieve data from URL (Eg: http://domain.com/index.php?var1=val1&var2=val2)

```
echo $_GET['var1']; (will return `val1`) and so on
```

POST - collect values in a HTML form with method="post", data send with curl with the same method, and so on.

```
<input name="username" />
echo $_POST['username'];
```

Use this like example, the actual content is more complex.